# How to use middleware and controller on one route

Tags: laravel, controller, cors, middleware

I have to add CORS policy to my request.
So I created middleware

I already tried the following :

```
Route::get('/test', ['middleware' => 'cors', 'cvGenerator@show'])
```

or

```
Route::get('/test', 'cvGenerator@show');
//inside controller 
$this->middleware('cors');
```

but none of the above work. CORS policy still aborted

my middleware code:

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class Cors
{
/**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Closure  $next
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    return $next($request)
  ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin' , '*')
  ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods' , 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS')
  ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers' , 'X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Origin, Cache-Control, Pragma, Authorization, Accept, Accept-Encoding');
}
}
```

And Controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use PDF;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
class cvGenerator extends Controller
{
public function show(Request $request)
{
$this->middleware('cors');
    echo 'test';
    //some code that generate output
   }
}
```

How can I pass the request?

Answer (score 1):

If you have just one route that should go through the middleware. Also middleware doesn’t belong in the controller.

```
Route::get('/test', 'cvGenerator@show')->middleware('cors');
```

If you have more than one route, you can use a route group.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['cors']], function () {
    Route::get('/test', 'cvGenerator@show');
});
```

Also Laravel has a pretty good docs about [middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/middleware).

---

**CORS**

We're using this middleware to support pre-flight [CORS](https://www.codecademy.com/articles/what-is-cors) requests:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class AddCorsHeaders
{
    /**
     * Check for CORS request.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param \Closure                 $next
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $headers = [
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'      => $request->header('Origin'),
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods'     => 'HEAD, POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers'     => $request->header('Access-Control-Request-Headers'),
        ];

        if ($request->isMethod('OPTIONS')) {
            return response()->json('{"method":"OPTIONS"}', 200, $headers);
        }

        if ($request->header('Origin')) {
            config(['access-control-origin' => $request->header('Origin')]);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

> Don't forget to add this to your `kernel.php` in the `$routeMiddleware` array.

```
'cors' => \App\Http\Middleware\AddCorsHeaders::class,
```

Comment: Route::get('/test')->middleware('cors');  and controller request schould be where?

Comment: the thing is, controller do main job he is generating pdf file and save it in bucket. but without corse he wont do anything xD

Comment: Whoops my bad, I updated the code blocks. Just after the route name. Example: `Route::get('/test', 'cvGenerator@show')`

Comment: i did it xD issue was becouse i forgott to add middleware in kornel middleware xD  but i have other issue... can you help me little bit more?

Comment: I like to help but if it's not about middleware you can better make a new issue for that question.

Comment: it is. everything working correct on localhost but when i add to elastic beanstalk i got 500 error... without cors app works without error but cant get request becouse cors

Comment: I added our CORS middleware.